# ubuntu 18.04 "Copy Paste" from ext4 to NTFS not possible

Tags: ntfs, ext4

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 along side win10.
While installing Ubuntu 18.04 along side win10, i have only these partitions

1. Recovery
2. EFI
3. MSReserved Partition
4. C Drive
5. Unallocated

when i was in something else screen, i have taken 33GB for "ext4 /" and left remaining space Unallocated.

Once Ubuntu is succsfully installed. I have gone through GParted and created two NTFS Partitions.

now i can not paste anything from ext4 to these NTFS

How can i resolve this?

[image]

Comment: The second one (/dev/sda7) is not mounted, so you can't access it now. The other one (dev/sda6) is mounted on /media/pratap/D but might be set to read-only if windows is not properly shut down (switch off the fast boot option).

Comment: What's the error you're getting??

Comment: No error.. When I copy something by right click in ext4 and go to Ntfs "paste" is greyed out.

Comment: Thanks to All. Turning off "fast boot" in win10 resolved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the same. When Fast boot is turned on in Win 10, I could only copy from NTFS partition, but can't paste in 18.04 (better than 16.04. In 16.04 it neither could read/write while fast boot is turned on!)

This happens when you shut down Windows 10. If the fast boot is on in Win 10, then during shutting down, Windows does not shut down HDD properly. It only Hibernates HDD (Windows provided this feature to increase boot-up speed & to increase security).
So at first turn off the "Fast boot" option in Power management in Win 10 and then shut down Windows 10. And then in Linux you can read/write in NTFS partition of HDD.